# Converting callback to Promise when I dont have the return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, node-rules

I am working on server that uses `hapi` and executes rules from `node-rules`.

I have a callback which is called by the `R.execute` method from `node-rules`. I need to return a `Promise` from the `exec` method as the result of executing the `callback`.

**Code**

```
const callback = data => {
  const {matchPath, result} = data
  descision.setMatchPath(matchPath)
  if (!result) {
    descision.addMessage(
      'No match could be found in the rules provided, either incorrect or non-matching information was provided'
    )
  }
}

function exec (input) {
  const {medicineType, facts: data} = input
  const R = new RuleEngine()
  R.register(rules)
  if (medicineType !== 'generic') {
    const facts = {
      data
    }
    R.execute(facts, callback)
  }
}
```

I noticed from the source code that `R.execute` does not return anything that I can use. I notice that in `execute` calls this [function here](https://github.com/mithunsatheesh/node-rules/blob/master/lib/node-rules.js#L55) recursively but does not terminate without the callback.

How can I convert this to a function that returns a Promise?

Comment: Why do you want to return a `Promise` instead of working with the `callback` function?

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla the `hapi` server is awaiting the result of the rule engine so that it can respond with a value, so I need to return a `Promise`.

Comment: `execute` might not return anything, but it calls the `callback` given to it. Ain't that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While browsing through some of the answers for other questions, I remembered the `$.deferred`and `Q.defer` API, I found a solution that resembles them:

1. creates a deferred
2. passes the deferred to the callback
3. uses the `deferred` and resolve the promise
4. and most importantly, return the `promise` that was created by the `deferred`

> I did not want a custom Promise implementation or to monkey-patch the `Promise` API. If the latter is not a problem, there are several modules on npm which do this and polyfill `Promise.defer`.

The `defer` function is [from here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/deferred-migration.html)

The code now looks like:

```
/* eslint-disable promise/param-names */
function defer () {
  let resolve, reject
  const promise = new Promise(function (...args) {
    resolve = args[0]
    reject = args[1]
  })
  return {resolve, reject, promise}
}

/* eslint-enable promise/param-names */

const makeCallback = deferred => data => {
  const {matchPath, result} = data
  descision.setMatchPath(matchPath)
  if (!result) {
    descision.addMessage(
      'No match could be found in the rules provided, either incorrect or non-matching information was provided'
    )
  }
  deferred.resolve(descision)
}

function exec (input) {
  const {medicineType, facts: data} = input
  const R = new RuleEngine()
  R.register(rules)
  if (lenderType !== 'generic') {
    const facts = {
      data
    }
    const deferred = defer()
    const callback = makeCallback(deferred)
    R.execute(facts, callback)
    return deferred.promise
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, you misunderstood how `await` work. It needs to get a promise, and `R.execute` with a callback doesn't return one.

Comment: @Bergi I agree that it should not work because there is no return value from the `R.execute` or the `callback` and no Promise was used, this is a bit  of concern for me as well. The library calls the callback using `process.nextTick`, is that a possible reason for it to wait until callback is invoked.

Comment: Yes. Please use the `new Promise` constructor to fix it.

Comment: @Bergi Removed, the false positive was because the callback finished before the next line could be reached as I did not have a sufficient number of rules to do a real test.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand correctly but something like this might do

```
function exec(input) {
    const { medicineType, facts: data } = input
    const R = new RuleEngine()
    R.register(rules)

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (medicineType !== 'generic') {
            const facts = {
                data
            }
            R.execute(facts, function(data) {
                const { matchPath, result } = data
                descision.setMatchPath(matchPath)
                if (!result) {
                    descision.addMessage(
                        'No match could be found in the rules provided, either incorrect or non-matching information was provided'
                    )
                }
                resolve('<return here whatever you want>')
                // or
                // reject('<return some error>')
            });
        } else {
            reject('<return some error>')
        }
    })
}
```